# How to invoker a signalr hub when calling a specific method in a web-api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, signalr

I just started learning about signalr and i just cannot understand the structure that it has.

Say i have this api endpoint:

```
public IActionResult Get()
{

   return Ok("You hit the endpoint!");

}
```

And i have implemented a hub like this:

```
public class MyHub: Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "You called the endpoint successfully", "");

    }
}
```

What i'm not understanding, is how can i call the endpoint above, and when the call is successful, i can get a signalr message saying "you called the endpoint successfully"?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using .Net Core application?

Comment: You could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51981886/11398810).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already done the client part of the code that connects to the SignalR hub, you just need to inject the hub in to your controller so you can call hub methods from that. Inject the hub in to controller using DI like:

```cs
private IHubContext<NotificationsHub, INotificationsHub> YourHub
{
    get
    {
        return this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHubContext<YourHub, IYourHub>>();
    }
}
```

and then invoke your hub method from action:

```cs
public IActionResult Get()
{
    this.YourHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "You called the endpoint successfully");
    return Ok("You hit the endpoint!");
}
```