# Signal-R implementation in .net core 3.1 mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, signalr

I have 3 projects in Asp.net core 3.1 MVC

1. Admin Project localhost:4001
2. Sales Project localhost:5001
3. Web Api for send all notifications in Signal-R  localhost:6001

Problem:
I have implemented signalR in Web api project like this **NotificationUserHub**  class

```cs
public class NotificationUserHub: Hub {
  private readonly IUserConnectionManager _userConnectionManager;
  public NotificationUserHub(IUserConnectionManager userConnectionManager) {
    _userConnectionManager = userConnectionManager;
  }
  public string ** GetConnectionId ** (string userId) {
    // var httpContext = this.Context.GetHttpContext();
    // var userId = httpContext.Request.Query["userId"];
    _userConnectionManager.KeepUserConnection(userId, Context.ConnectionId);

    return Context.ConnectionId;
  }
  //Called when a connection with the hub is terminated.
  public async override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception) {
    //get the connectionId
    var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
    _userConnectionManager.RemoveUserConnection(connectionId);
    var value = await Task.FromResult(0); //adding dump code to follow the template of Hub > OnDisconnectedAsync
  }
}
```

I have add client side code in Admin project to get first connection id from api and pass in to redis cache and get from redis cache all user connect ids to send notifications but no notification showing in client profile.

Get connection ids from redis cache and send to client

```cs
var ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(ENVIRONMENT) + "_";
var list = new ImplementRedis().GetFullHash(ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT + CONNECTION_PREFIX);
userConnectionMap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Dictionary < string, List < string >> [] > (list)[0];
var userId = "1136";
if (userConnectionMap.ContainsKey(userId)) {
  var getConnections = userConnectionMap[userId].ToArray();
  foreach(var connectionId in getConnections) {
    await _notificationUserHubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("sendToUser", "Test", "test 123");
  }
}
```

ClientSide code in Admin project.

```cs
connection = new
signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("@baseUrl/api/home").build();
connection.on("sendToUser", (header, body) => {
  debugger;
  LoadNotificationItem();
  ShowNotificationPopup(header, "");
});

**
connection.start().catch(function(err) {
  return console.error(err.toString());
}).then(function() {
  debugger;
  connection.invoke('GetConnectionId').then(function(connectionId) {
    debugger;
    document.getElementById('signalRConnectionId').innerHTML = connectionId;
  })
}); **
```

we cannot calling to getconnectionid from api how can i call?

**Requirement:**
Create one hub in web APi project and maintain all connectionIds in this project.
Send all notifications in database from Api project so i will send all notification from Signal R

Display notifications in All modules where client is staying active modules like sales module is using by client so notify on this project.

How can implement in .net core 3.1 mvc ?

Comment: Hi @Asad Shaikh, What do you mean for `we cannot calling to getconnectionid from api how can i call?`?I think you need read this answer first:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968201/invoking-signalr-hub-not-working-for-asp-net-core-web-api.